# Get Mamp Apache/PHP to be case sensitive like remote server

Tags: php, apache, case-sensitive

I was wondering if there was a way to get MAMP and Apache on my mac behave like on the server. It is very annoying that everything works fine offline and once its online its a hassle because the system is case sensitive. Is that something I can just for my dev environment or will it mess up my whole OS?

Answer (score 0):

The default OS X file system is case insensitive.  There is nothing you can do in Apache or PHP to simulate case sensitivity because it's handled at the OS level.  There are a few options for switching to case sensitive local files:

- Add a new drive or partition and use a case sensitive file system.  Place your project there.  This is probably the easiest fix.
- Reformat your Mac to be case sensitive.  This won't be a problem for OS X but can have negative side affects on other applications (e.g. Adobe).
- Run Apache and PHP inside a local virtual machine with the same OS as your server.  You can edit files locally and mount the working directory inside the VM.  This is a good method if you want to debug inside an environment very similar to your server.